# Regex expression to exclude set of options

Tags: java, regex

This is input string `253:13:2a`

Conditions:

- 1) first part is fixed. Always starts with 253
- 2) Last part is also
  fixed. Always 2a
- 3) First digit of middle can have 0-2. And Second
  digit position can have 0-9.

I want to exclude middle possible numbers like 00,12,19.

e.g.

```
253:13:2a // is correct
but 253:00:2a // not correct
253:19:2a // not correct
```

I am using the below regex but it does not work as desired.

```
^253:[[0-2][0-9]]&&[^[(00)(12)(19))]]:2a$
```

Comment: @timgeb : Updated. Only to remove 00, 12 and 19.

Comment: @Tushar : Language Java

Comment: Please always add the language/tool tag when asking about regex (I did it for you). It's very frequent to have to tailor the regex for the flavour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
^253:(?!00)(?!12)(?!19)[0-2][0-9]:2a$
```

This one uses a negative look-ahead to exclude inputs containing "00", "12" and "19".

If you *really* want to do it without lookaheads, here's how:

```
^253:(0[1-9]|1[013-8]|2[0-9]):2a$
```

This one would be very marginally faster but I would choose the one that mimic the best the logic behind, so that it's easier to maintain.

Comment: Just the perfect one. Thanks. Now I understood what are the mistakes that I made.

Comment: In your first approach is the code walk through is as follows: after matching 253: the engine will look forward two positions and if it does not find 00 then continue to look next two positions for 12 and if all the three numbers were not found then ONLY match [0-2][0-9]. Else simply return from the place where any of the numbers (00 or 12 or 19) were found and should not proceed to match [0-2][0-9] ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead and alternate between all the numbers you don't want to match:

```
^253:(?!(00|12|19):)\d+:2a$
```

Demo and step-by-step explanation: https://regex101.com/r/nQ3uX2/3

Comment: @user3243499 why do you suddenly want a regex without lookaheads?

Comment: I have read somewhere that lookahead can be slippery and also it uses extra memories

Comment: @user3243499 no, this regex won't be slippery. If you are concerned about the memory consumption for this tiny regex then a regex is not the right tool for the job. Are you writing software for a toaster or something?